# Gradle, NetBeans 12.2, OpenJDK 13 cause a null pointer exception EXCEPT when "Evaluate Expression" is used

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans

I have a gradle project (6.8.3) that contains several sub-projects. I am using NetBeans 12.2

One of the subprojects (SPA) contains a compileOnly reference to a jar that is included as implementation in another (SPB). SPA is a dependency of SPB (entry point). The identifying string is identical in both projects

mainProject.label + ':X.X.X'

Project and subprojects compile without a problem.

The first reference to an *instance* of a class from this jar in code from SPA (called by SPB) causes a NPE while running/debugging the code. But if I execute the offending code in the "Evaluate Expression" window, it executes flawlessly.

I have checked that no null values exist at the moment of execution.

Any ideas? I have cleaned up m2 repos, gradle caches, etc.

EDIT 1:

After further inspection the NPE comes from Thread.java:830.

The method is setName(...) It explicitly throws an NPE if name is null. But the two threads used in this logic have already been created and their names have already been set. I can see them in NetBeans callstack. The code is trying to get a property of the instance in question

Edit 2:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.packages.MyClass.run(MyClass.java:65)<-*first reference to instance*
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Edit 3:

I have tried 3 different classloaders as a parent of the custom loading that the logic performs. None of them fail to load the classes or instantiate objects.

It does not seem be a problem if executed inside the IDE expression evaluator.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: I will but not really helpful

Comment: Done. As previously stated the stack trace does not help much other than finding the line where the exception is thrown

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was none of the above to an extent.

It was a missing cast. The Expression Evaluator uses the correct type without needing a cast.  After the explicit cast running and debugging work as expected